# Calling stored procedure from Entity Framework Code First with Database.SqlQuery is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I am trying to call a stored procedure from my `DbContext`, but I am getting an error on the SQL that is being generated. The generated TSQL by EF has this error :

> The parameterized query expects the parameter ..., which was not supplied

How could I fix the EF query to create the proper call to the stored procedure?

My code looks like this. It is long but simple. It is declaring first the parameters names and the stored procedure name. Then using the `DbContext` and `Database.SqlQuery` to call the stored procedure with created `SqlParamter`s. At the end its showed the SQL that is being generated by this call.

```
const string PayerId = "@PayerId";
const string ProviderId = "@ProviderId";
const string LineOfBusinessId = "@LineOfBusinessId";
const string PracticeLocationId = "@PracticeLocationId";
const string ClinicalCodingCategoryId = "@ClinicalCodingCategoryId";
const string FacilityName = "@FacilityName";
const string FacilityType = "@FacilityType";
const string ServiceDate = "@ServiceDate";
const string MilesFromPracticeLocation = "@MilesFromPracticeLocation";
const string GetPossibleSiteofServiceName = "getPossibleSiteofService";

var payerId = new Guid("5a4a16c3-d352-e411-80db-00155d66b519"); 
var providerId = new Guid("89516ad4-D852-E411-80DB-00155D66B519");
var lineOfBusinessId = new Guid("a2b3bcf3-9ab3-e311-80c3-00155d66cdf0"); 
var practiceLocationId = new Guid("36561da7-d852-e411-80db-00155d66b519"); 
var clinicalCodingCategoryId = new Guid("d541b72f-7ca3-e411-80db-00155d66b519");
string facilityName = null;
string facilityType = null;
Nullable<DateTime> serviceDate = null;
var milesFromPracticeLocation = 20;

using (var context = new AnalyticContext())
{
    var payerIdParameter = new SqlParameter(PayerId, payerId);
    var providerIdParameter = new SqlParameter(ProviderId, providerId);
    var lineOfBusinessIdParameter = new SqlParameter(LineOfBusinessId, lineOfBusinessId);
    var practiceLocationIdParameter = new SqlParameter(PracticeLocationId, practiceLocationId);
    var clinicalCodingCategoryIdParameter = new SqlParameter(ClinicalCodingCategoryId, clinicalCodingCategoryId);
    var facilityNameParameter = new SqlParameter(FacilityName, facilityName);
    var facilityTypeParameter = new SqlParameter(FacilityType, facilityType);
    var serviceDateParameter = new SqlParameter(ServiceDate, serviceDate);
    var milesFromPracticeLocationParameter = new SqlParameter(MilesFromPracticeLocation, milesFromPracticeLocation);

    var data = context.Database
                   .SqlQuery<PossibleSiteofService>(GetPossibleSiteofServiceName, payerIdParameter, 
                        providerIdParameter, lineOfBusinessIdParameter, 
                        practiceLocationIdParameter, 
                        clinicalCodingCategoryIdParameter, 
                        facilityNameParameter, facilityTypeParameter, 
                        serviceDateParameter, milesFromPracticeLocationParameter)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
            }
```

Generated SQL code :

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'getPossibleSiteofService',
N'@PayerId uniqueidentifier,
@ProviderId uniqueidentifier,
@LineOfBusinessId uniqueidentifier,
@PracticeLocationId uniqueidentifier,
@ClinicalCodingCategoryId uniqueidentifier,
@FacilityName nvarchar(4000),
@FacilityType nvarchar(4000),
@ServiceDate nvarchar(4000),
@MilesFromPracticeLocation int',
@PayerId='5A4A16C3-D352-E411-80DB-00155D66B519',
@ProviderId='89516AD4-D852-E411-80DB-00155D66B519',
@LineOfBusinessId='A2B3BCF3-9AB3-E311-80C3-00155D66CDF0',
@PracticeLocationId='36561DA7-D852-E411-80DB-00155D66B519',
@ClinicalCodingCategoryId='D541B72F-7CA3-E411-80DB-00155D66B519',
@FacilityName=default,
@FacilityType=default,
@ServiceDate=default,
@MilesFromPracticeLocation=20
```

The stored procedure is very simple something like this:

```
[dbo].[getPossibleSiteofService]
    @PayerId UniqueIdentifier, --Required
    @ProviderId UniqueIdentifier, --Required
    @LineOfBusinessId UniqueIdentifier, --Required
    @PracticeLocationId UniqueIdentifier, --Required
    @ClinicalCodingCategoryId UniqueIdentifier, --Required
    @FacilityName varchar(255) = NULL, --Optional
    @FacilityType varchar(255) = NULL, --Optional
    @ServiceDate DateTime = NULL, --Optional Will Default to CURRENT DTM
    @MilesFromPracticeLocation int = NULL --Optional
AS
....
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems last year and found my solution to be this:

The solution for this problem (in my case was)

```
var stuff = db.Database.SqlQuery<SomeEntityType>(query, parms);
```

Where query was a string that had parameters inserted such as @Name etc. The parms variable was a List of SQLParameters. SQL doesn't like generic lists....

SQL must have an array of SQLParameters sent as and object[] and not a list of generic type.

```
var stuff = db.Database.SqlQuery<SomeEntityType>(query, parms.ToArray());
```

Comment: This solution does not work I tested and the TSQL that is generated duplicate the input parameters @Parm. Also I create the list and then the array with the parameters to see if that make a solution but is the same result.

Comment: This the TSQL that is generating with duplicates: exec sp_executesql N'getPossibleSiteofService @PayerId...,N'@PayerId uniqueidentifier,@ProviderId uniqueidentifier...@FacilityName=default,@FacilityType=default,@ServiceDate=default,@MilesFromPracticeLocation=20

Comment: Figure out why there are duplicate parm names, this should never happen and creates the root cause of your issue.  You don't have to even have them generated (using DB first) you  can manually create the query and the parms as well.

Answer (score -1):

Add your stored procedure to EDMX/Model same like you added tables
then you can access your stored procedure as function with context object

You need to do this
open 'EDMX/Model' file 
then open Model Browser'
and expend 'Stored Procedures' node 
right click your procedure and click 'Add Function Import'

Now you can access your sp as function like

```
context.getPossibleSiteofService(payerId, providerId, lineOfBusinessId, clinicalCodingCategoryId....., milesFromPracticeLocation)
```

**when using SP as function then no need for SQL paremeters, you can directly use the C# variables as you have assigned values.

Comment: this 'milesFromPracticeLocation' is a INT not var, change to int and then pass to sp